# Change tempDB drive SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to change the drive for the tempDB on a production SQL Server 2008 R2. Does this require a restart and are there any gotchas I need to look out for?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty broad question that I am sure has been answered but oh well.

Changing the tempdb drive location does require restarting the SQL instance and I would strongly suggest keeping it where it is and moving other stuff FROM that drive. I normally avoid it at all costs at my work place personally just because I dont like having to alter the original install and also dont like to be forced to restart the SQL instance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx